# Connection failed, address = pub.dartlang.org, port = 443 flutter visual studio Mac big sur

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a new flutter project using Visual Studio code, but it is not working.
what is the problem? how can fix this

[screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETSjt.png)

Comment: Did you try to ping the server using the following command? `ping pub.dartlang.org`. Are properly connected to the internet or behind a (corporate) proxy?

Comment: did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by upgrading to the latest flutter version. flutter_macos_2.2.3-stable